# Error while SUDOing

Tags: sudo

I am facing a issue. When I try to do `sudo` on my terminal I get:

```
sudo: must be setuid root
```

I googled for the problem and did as the suggestions like setting permission of sudo but they were already in the required state. Cannot figure out what may be the problem. Please help.

Thanks

Output of `mount`:

```
 /dev/sda8 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro) 
 proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev) 
 sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev) 
 none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw) 
 none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
 none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw) 
 udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
 devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
 tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
 none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
 none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
 /dev/sda6 on /home type ext4 (rw)
 /dev/sda7 on /var type ext4 (rw)
 /home/incaendo/.Private on /home/incaendo type ecryptfs (ecryptfs_check_dev_ruid,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs,ecryptfs_sig=b746275454680798,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=2164f6a8d7aa74c7)
 gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/incaendo/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=incaendo)
```

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l $(which sudo)`?

Comment: its  -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 69708 Jun  1  2012 /usr/bin/sudo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying all then suggestions given to me, The only way was to Re install Ubuntu and that is what I have to do Finally.

Answer (score 5):

Reinstalling the **sudo** package using

```
pkexec apt-get --reinstall install sudo
```

will set sudo's setuid flag. If that fails, try reinstalling it using your graphical package manager or `aptitude`. If that fails too, set sudo's setuid bit manually:

```
pkexec chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo
```

If that fails as well with error *"pkexec: must be setuid root"*, then check that the filesystem containing `/usr/bin` hasn't been accidentally mounted with the `nosuid` option set. Examine the output of `mount`.

If that is not the case either, then check if *any* binary in `/usr/bin` has its setuid bit set, using:

```
find /usr/bin -perm 4755
```

This should list at least `passwd`, `sudo`, and the likes. If there is none, then surely a stray cosmic ray has kicked those setuid bits over (or maybe this was you after all, with an overzealous `chmod -s *` because it is rumoured that setuid is bad?)

Either way, you will first have to reestablish your sudo rights. I have described the way to do that in a [separate answer](/a/264693/134479) to this question. Once you have those, reinstall every package containing a setuid binary, or chmod each binary manually, as shown at the top of this answer.

---

Unfortunately, as the answer to [another question](/q/107374/134479) states, there is no easy way to find out which binaries in Ubuntu are installed setuid root.

Here is, for reference, the list on a nearly pristine 12.04. Package names on the left, binaries on the right of the colon:

```
$ find {/usr,}/bin -perm 4755 | xargs dpkg -S
passwd: /usr/bin/chsh
iputils-tracepath: /usr/bin/traceroute6.iputils
mtr-tiny: /usr/bin/mtr
passwd: /usr/bin/gpasswd
sudo: /usr/bin/sudoedit
login: /usr/bin/newgrp
passwd: /usr/bin/chfn
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo
passwd: /usr/bin/passwd
login: /bin/su
iputils-ping: /bin/ping
mount: /bin/umount
mount: /bin/mount
fuse: /bin/fusermount
iputils-ping: /bin/ping6
```

Comment: @SankalpMishra it will be helpful for later reference if you could add to the question the reason why the setuid bits got lost in the first place.

Comment: I don't know why why the asker lost their setuid bits, but I've recently discovered that chown automatically wipes all setuid bits, though the man page doesn't mention this. I had a genius idea that involved temporarily changing the owner of most of my top-level directories to a non-root user, thinking this would change nothing in the long run. I don't recommend trying it. Even after I used a virtual console to login as root and chown-ed them back, I'd still lost all my setuid bits. I imagine trying to restore your system from backups could have similar problems if done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The issue the OP has is that *all* setuid root binaries in `/usr/bin` have somehow lost their setuid bit. This causes the bootstrapping problem of setting the setuid bit back on `/usr/bin/sudo` without being able to `sudo`. Here is how to do just that:

1. Reboot and in the Grub menu, select the "recovery mode" option.
2. When the recovery menu appears, select "root" to drop to a root shell.
3. Remount the root filesystem to be writeable:

   ```
   # mount -o remount,rw /
   ```
4. Set the setuid bit on sudo and pkexec:

   ```
   # chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/pkexec
   ```

Exit recovery mode and continue regular boot.

Comment: Thaks Zewts for wonderful help. ..But unfortunately, none brought luck to me!!:(.. Finally i have to re install the ubuntu